# PDFKit middleware problem on Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit, rack-middleware

I have installed PDFKit and wkhtmltopdf on my Ubuntu 8.04 server. I am trying to use PDFKit as middleware in my Rails 2.3.8 app and have added the following lines to environment.rb (as directed on the jdpace pdfkit page):

require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware

My Mongrel seems to start up but as soon as I request a page the following error appears in the Mongrel log:

** Writing PID file to tmp/pids/mongrel.9270.pid
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Sep 07 16:42:20 +0000 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pdfkit-0.4.6/lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:12:in`call'
    /home/rails/livetest-carbon-hub/releases/20100907133547/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in`call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'

Has anybody else come across this ?

Any help or suggestions gratefully received !

Answer (score 2):

require 'pdfkit' needs to be above the

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

and

config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware

needs to be underneath, inside the run block.

You probably also want to add

config.gem 'pdfkit'

and

Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf

in there as well.